# AutoCapitalize Tkinter Entry text input

Tags: tkinter

Is there a relatively easy way to automatically capitalize a Tkinter Entry's text input in realtime? So as a user is inputting values, they automatically get capitalized. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be easily accomplished with [`trace`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm#patterns) and [`str.capitalize`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize):

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
var = StringVar()
entry = Entry(root, textvariable=var)
entry.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

def autocapitalize(*arg):
    var.set(var.get().capitalize())

var.trace("w", autocapitalize)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'm running into issues with my class, I don't think Im getting the function to work properly. http://pastebin.com/9zJtq74n Do you know how I could get your answer to work in my context! Super thanks!

Comment: @TheoretiCAL The problem is that `func` is not defined. Also, in `wat==True` and `eng==True` you are using the reference of the widget. You should change it to simply `wat.get()` and `eng.get()`.

Comment: Oh I figured out the capitalize problem, I changed it to .upper() instead for the function and it worked. Thanks for the reference tip! I have func defined above the gui, so that was fine. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can bind to an event instead of using `.trace()` (in python 3.x, not tested in 2.x).

For details see my answer to this similar question: [python - Converting entry() values to upper case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44105484/python-converting-entry-values-to-upper-case)