# python - Converting entry() values to upper case

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make the values I type on Entry field to be automatically converted to uppercase. I have code in here that only accepts uppercase letters to be typed in the entry using validatecommand.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
def text(a,b,c):
    ind=int(b)
    if c == '1': #insert
        if not a[ind].isupper():
            return False
    return True

 entry = Entry(root, validate="key")
 entry['validatecommand'] = (entry.register(text),'%P','%i','%d')
 entry.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If the user can't enter anything other than uppercase, why do you need to convert it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert the entry content to uppercase instead of preventing the user to insert non uppercase letters, you can associate a `StringVar` to your entry and use its `trace` (`trace_add` since python 3.6) method to convert the entry content to uppercase each time the user modifies the entry.

`trace` takes two arguments: the mode and the callback. The mode determines when the callback is called.  The modes are:

- `'w'` (`'write'` for python 3.6): the callback is called when the variable is written (it's the mode I use in the code below),
- `'r'` (`'read'`): the callback is called when the variable is read,
- `'u'` (`'unset'`): the callback is called when the variable is deleted

For more details about the arguments of the callback, see [What are the arguments to Tkinter variable trace method callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29690463/what-are-the-arguments-to-tkinter-variable-trace-method-callbacks)

```
import tkinter as tk

def to_uppercase(*args):
    var.set(var.get().upper())

root = tk.Tk()

var = tk.StringVar(root)
e = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var)
e.pack()
try:
    # python 3.6
    var.trace_add('write', to_uppercase)
except AttributeError:
    # python < 3.6
var.trace('w', to_uppercase)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind to an event instead of using .trace (in python 3.x, not tested in 2.x).

The following is copied verbatum from the accepted answer (by "bevdet") to 
https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/897918-how-do-i-make-tkinter-text-entry-all-uppercase.

---

You can bind an event to your widget that calls a function to convert the text to upper case. 
You will need to initialize a textvariable for the Entry widget. In your case, there is nothing else to take the focus, otherwise you could bind < FocusOut > to the widget. < KeyRelease > works nicely however.

```
from Tkinter import *
win = Tk()

def caps(event):
    v.set(v.get().upper())

Label(win, text='Enter user nick:').pack(side=LEFT)
v = StringVar()
w = Entry(win, width=20, textvariable=v)
w.pack(side=LEFT)
w.bind("<KeyRelease>", caps)

mainloop()
```

---

I was able to use this method in combination with custom validation (See B. Oakley answer to 
[Interactively validating Entry widget content in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140437/interactively-validating-entry-widget-content-in-tkinter)) by placing the binding OUTSIDE the validation function, immediately after creating the Entry widget. *Important: Do not put the binding inside the validation function, doing so will break the validation function* (see accepted answer to [Python tkInter Entry fun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019782/python-tkinter-entry-fun) for explanation and a possible workaround).